# How to parse data multi row and multi line string and extract data onto JSON file using Python

Tags: python, json, list

Im trying to add data below onto JSON file..this is just a sample as Im still learning how to do it.

```
ITEM    QTY   ID        DESCR   LOCATION                    
item1   3     it111     Gold    Rack11      
item2   10    it222     Silver  Rack22   
item3   6     it333     Red     Rack33      
item4   1     it444     Blue    Rack44
```

for example below i can add class and owner value because its only single line and single string output. But the key details output composed of multi-line of key and value and Im not sure how to read it line by line and parse to json.

```
{
     "product": [
        {
         "class":"food",
         "owner":"user1",
        }
     ]
}
```

Final output expected like below

```
{
     "product": [
        {
         "class":"food",
         "owner":"user1",
         "details": [
         {
          "item":"item1",
          "qty":"3",
          "id":"it111",
          "desc":"Gold",
          "loct":"Rack11"
         },
         {
          "item":"item2",
          "qty":"10",
          "id":"it222",
          "desc":"Silver",
          "loct":"Rack22"
         },
         {
          "item":"item3",
          "qty":"6",
          "id":"it333",
          "desc":"Red",
          "loct":"Rack33"
         },
         {
          "item":"item4",
          "qty":"1",
          "id":"it444",
          "desc":"Blue",
          "loct":"Rack44"
         }
        ] 
       }
     ]
}
```

My list like below

```
product = "class","owner","details"
```

The problem is I dont know how to get details output onto "details" and form it onto json nested structure. 
Appreciated your help. Thank you

---

Using csv reader is the solution here if the input text is tab delimited. It works...as advised below. Based on the info...I try applying the same with another set of input text similar and it give me an error of

```
ValueError: need more than 4 values to unpack
```

sample set of input text as below

```
Local Interface   Parent Interface   Chassis Id          Port info    System Name
xe-3/0/4.0        ae31.0             b0:c6:9a:63:80:40   xe-0/0/0.0   host.xsrt1.net
xe-3/0/5.0        ae31.0             b0:c6:9a:63:80:40   xe-0/0/1.0   host.xsrt1.net
xe-3/0/6.0        ae31.0             b0:c6:9a:63:80:40   xe-0/0/2.0   host.xsrt1.net
xe-3/0/7.0        ae31.0             b0:c6:9a:63:80:40   xe-0/0/3.0   host.xsrt1.net
xe-3/0/0.0        ae31.0             b0:c6:9a:63:80:40   xe-0/1/0.0   host.xsrt1.net
xe-3/0/1.0        ae31.0             b0:c6:9a:63:80:40   xe-0/1/1.0   host.xsrt1.net
xe-3/0/2.0        ae31.0             b0:c6:9a:63:80:40   xe-0/1/2.0   host.xsrt1.net
xe-3/0/3.0        ae31.0             b0:c6:9a:63:80:40   xe-0/1/3.0   host.xsrt1.net
```

Im not sure why... but maybe it is not exactly a tab delimited format..if this is the case how to convert it to valid tab delimited format? Thanks

**Update1**: for the above input i split into lines with the test code below

```
with open('lldp.csv', 'r', newline='') as csv_file:
   reader = csv.reader(line.replace('  ', ',') for line in csv_file)
   my_list = list(reader)
   pprint(my_list)
```

The output as below

```
[['Local Interface',' Parent Interface',' Chassis Id','','','','','Port 
info','','System Name'],['xe-3/0/4.0','','','','ae31.0','','','','','',' 
b0:c6:9a:63:80:40',' xe-0/0/0.0',' host.jnpr.net'],['xe- 
3/0/5.0','','','','ae31.0','','','','','',' b0:c6:9a:63:80:40',' xe- 
0/0/1.0',' host.jnpr.net'],['xe-3/0/6.0','','','','ae31.0','','','','','',' 
b0:c6:9a:63:80:40',' xe-0/0/2.0',' host.jnpr.net'],['xe- 
3/0/7.0','','','','ae31.0','','','','','',' b0:c6:9a:63:80:40',' xe- 
0/0/3.0',' host.jnpr.net'],['xe-3/0/0.0','','','','ae31.0','','','','','',' 
b0:c6:9a:63:80:40',' xe-0/1/0.0',' host.jnpr.net'],['xe- 
3/0/1.0','','','','ae31.0','','','','','',' b0:c6:9a:63:80:40',' xe- 
0/1/1.0',' host.jnpr.net'],['xe-3/0/2.0','','','','ae31.0','','','','','',' 
b0:c6:9a:63:80:40',' xe-0/1/2.0',' host.jnpr.net'],['xe- 
3/0/3.0','','','','ae31.0','','','','','',' b0:c6:9a:63:80:40',' xe- 
0/1/3.0',' host.jnpr.net']]
```

From above how to remove unwanted '' and how to start read the line from 2nd line (the 1st line is only the header). From the list i want to parse it onto json as specified above.

*I will open a new question for my question above and to focus on the output above Thanks*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use **csv reader** if the columns are tab-delimited.

First you create a basic dictionary with the `"class"` and `"owner"` values and an empty list for `"details"`. Then you parse rows one by one and add individual details.

```
import csv
import json

out = {
    "product": [
        {
            "class": "food",
            "owner": "user1",
            "details": []
        }
    ]
}

with open("data.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
    next(reader) # skip header

    for row in reader:

        detail = {
            "item": row[0],
            "qty" : row[1],
            "id"  : row[2],
            "desc": row[3],
            "loct": row[4]
        }

        out["product"][0]["details"].append(detail)

# now out contains the final dictionary, you can output it like this:
print(json.dumps(out, indent=4))
```

It is not clear to me why would you have `"product"` as a list if you have only a single item in it -- I guess you will then enrich the list with more products.

Comment: Hi.noted and thank you sir. I try applying to another set input data which is not tab delimited and it doesn't work..i have update the sample non tab delimited above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're iterating over the initial list of class and ownder, but his will generate your desired output:

```
import pandas as pd
import json


data = [
['item1','3','it111','Gold','Rack11'],
['item2','10','it222','Silver','Rack22'],  
['item3','6','it333','Red','Rack33'],      
['item4','1','it444','Blue','Rack44']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['ITEM','QTY','ID','DESCR','LOCATION'])

#Above was so I had the data to work with, but you can read it in with pandas if its an excel or csv file

# df = pd.read_csv('path/to/datafile.csv')

jsonDict = {}
jsonDict["product"] = []
jsonDict["product"].append({})

jsonDict["product"][0]["class"] = "food"
jsonDict["product"][0]["owner"] = "user1"
jsonDict["product"][0]["details"] = []

for i, row in df.iterrows():

    temp_dict = {}
    temp_dict['item'] = row['ITEM'] 
    temp_dict['qty'] = row['QTY'] 
    temp_dict['id_num'] = row['ID'] 
    temp_dict['desc'] = row['DESCR'] 
    temp_dict['loct'] = row['LOCATION'] 

    jsonDict["product"][0]["details"].append(temp_dict)

with open('data.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(jsonDict, fp, indent=3, sort_keys=False)
```